# Python reduce drops first element of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to sum items stored in a list using reduce() using a lambda expression. I am getting some odd behavior that I can't get a handle on.

An example

```
>>> digits = [1,2,3]
>>> print(list(map(lambda y:digits[y],[i for i in range(len(digits))])))
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y,digits))
6
>>> print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + digits[y],[i for i in range(len(digits))]))
5
```

Why does map catch all elements when iterating over the indices, but if I iterate over the indices and not the list itself, reduce loses the first element?

Comment: Because the first index, `0` is used as the initial value, so it's `0 + digits[1]`, in the case where you don't use indices, it's `1 + 2`. Note, you'd need `digits[x] + digits[y]` on the first iteration, followed by `accumulator + digits[y]` on the second... Try using a full function definition with some `prints` to see how the function is working in both cases.

Comment: So, one solution that will work for *both* attempts would be to pass the initial value as the second argument, i.e. `reduce( <func>, <iterable>, 0)`

Comment: FWIW, `[i for i in range(len(digits))]` is equivalent to `range(len(digits))` in this context.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if you post your second comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @wjandrea, lol, I was so worked up trying to understand what reduce was doing, I didn't notice that. Thanks for pointing that out.